No matter how I change a loss function I get it equal to infinity
I am a bioinformatician, and at the moment I am working with a dataset containing ~12.3 million mutations for ~5500 individuals. The goal is to perform binary classification. I use this framework to create the model, it's called GenNet.
The problem is that my dataset is severely imbalanced, it has a ~9:1 ratio. Controls and cases are annotated by 0 and 1 respectively.
The current iteration of the loss function looks like this, added assertions and print statements to monitor what is happening. I even used the unweighted Keras BCE function in the hope that it would help me to deal with inf values and added weights to it:
def check_for_nan_or_inf(tensor, name):
    tf.print(name, tensor)
    tf.debugging.assert_all_finite(tensor, f"{name} contains NaN or Inf values")

def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float32)
    y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, tf.keras.backend.epsilon(), 1 - tf.keras.backend.epsilon())

    # Use tf.print for printing tensor values in graph mode
    tf.print('*' * 100)
    tf.print('Y_TRUE:', y_true)
    tf.print('*' * 100)
    tf.print('Y_PRED:', y_pred)

    # Create weights based on the class (y_true values)
    weights = (y_true * (weight_positive_class - weight_negative_class)) + weight_negative_class
    weights = tf.cast(weights, tf.float32)  # Ensure weights are float32
    tf.print('*' * 100)
    tf.print('WEIGHTS:', weights)
    tf.print('*' * 100)
    tf.print("WEIGHT FOR POSITIVE CLASS:", weight_positive_class)
    tf.print('*' * 100)
    tf.print("WEIGHT FOR NEGATIVE CLASS:", weight_negative_class)

    # Calculate the binary crossentropy
    bce = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    bce = tf.cast(bce, tf.float32)  # Ensure bce is float32
    tf.print('*' * 100)
    tf.print('BCE:', bce)

    # Check for NaN or Inf values
    check_for_nan_or_inf(y_true, 'Y_TRUE')
    check_for_nan_or_inf(y_pred, 'Y_PRED')
    check_for_nan_or_inf(weights, 'WEIGHTS')
    check_for_nan_or_inf(bce, 'BCE')

    # Apply the weights
    weighted_bce = tf.reduce_mean(bce * weights)
    tf.print('*' * 100)
    tf.print('WEIGHTED_BCE:', weighted_bce)

    # Check for NaN or Inf values in the final loss
    check_for_nan_or_inf(weighted_bce, 'WEIGHTED_BCE')

    return weighted_bce

Here is an example of weighted_binary_crossentropy prints:

Y_TRUE: [[0]
         [0]
         [0]
         ...
         [0]
         [0]
         [0]]
            *****************************************************************************************

Y_PRED: [[0.510742188]
         [0.506835938]
         [0.512207031]
         ...
         [0.514648438]
         [0.513183594]
         [0.512207031]]
            *****************************************************************************************

WEIGHTS: [[0.566014647]
          [0.566014647]
          [0.566014647]
          ...
          [0.566014647]
          [0.566014647]
          [0.566014647]]
            *****************************************************************************************

WEIGHT FOR POSITIVE CLASS: 4.2870369
            *****************************************************************************************

WEIGHT FOR NEGATIVE CLASS: 0.566014647
  *****************************************************************************************

BCE: [0.714865446 0.706913114 0.717864 ... 0.722881556 0.719867945 0.717864]

***************************************************************************************** 

WEIGHTED_BCE: 0.569198668


Judging by the print statements and assertions everything is relatively normal, at least returned weighted_BCE is not infinity. But somewhere downstream the loss function becomes infinity and I cannot figure out where and why. I contacted the author but he remains silent, unfortunately. The loss function works fine on a test dataset that came with the framework.
Also, just in case, I am copy-pasting the command I run from jupyter notebook to launch the framework.
%%timeit

weight_positive_class = (1 / 648) * (4908 + 648) / 2.0
weight_negative_class = (1 / 4908) * (4908 + 648) / 2.0

%run GenNet/GenNet.py train -path /home/aydar/DataspellProjects/GenNet/GenNet/processed_data/01_data_prepared_for_analysis_final/ -out /home/aydar/DataspellProjects/GenNet/results/ -bs 16 -lr 0.002 -ID 2 -epochs 50 -wpc $weight_positive_class -wnc $weight_negative_class -mixed_precision -workers 12

As I figured out the main model training module is this one. The generators that provide data for training_network.py are defined here. Also, Create_network.py module seem important, but I can't figure out the exact way it is used. Please help, as I am debugging code line by line at the moment and it is just painful. I would appreciate it. Thanks.

did you check if any of y_pred is extremely close to 0 or 1 and is a wrong prediction?
